# How to get GraphDatabaseService instance from Bolt Driver

Tags: neo4j

I wrote some codes that used java Api of `GraphDatabaseService` to access an embedded database before. But now I want to switch the database to a remote one, so I have to use `Driver` and `Session` class to write and run cyphers. I don't like cyphers and I don't want to change the old codes.

So I'm looking for a way so that I can get `GraphDatabaseService` from `Driver`, but none is found.

I think a possible way is to make up a `GraphDataBaseService` delegate that wraps a `Driver` and converts Api calls to cyphers. Is that feasible? Is there already some libraries which can do this?

Answer (score 0):

You won't get a direct equivalent of `GraphDatabaseService` since that's the embedded API.
You can however run Cypher queries like this:

```java
        var driver = GraphDatabase.driver(
                "some://address",
                AuthTokens.basic("username", "password")
        );
        // [...]
        try (var session = driver.session() {
            return session.writeTransaction(tx -> {
                Result result = tx.run(
                        "CYPHER QUERY",
                        Map.of(/* query parameters */)
                );
                // do something with result
            });
        }
        // [...]
        driver.close(); // (driver is usually a singleton - closes when application shuts down)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to make a [project](https://github.com/MasterQiao/Dasiy) to solve this problem by wrapping Driver to GraphDatabaseService.